# Mozilla Firefox, position fixed bug

Tags: html, css, firefox, semantic-ui

I have Semantic UI table. Table header row all datas are with position fixed. In all browser are shown proper, but in Mozilla Firefox all are on top of each other, because it shows position fixed like position absolute.

Do you have any ideas how to fix that?

Check differences between chrome and firefox... !IMPORTANT(1.Expand a result window little bit, 2.scroll down, 3.click anywhere in table!!!!!)
Answer from Semantic UI creators: [noUse](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2714#issuecomment-124354188)
Problem exist in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox, did not exist in Chrome and Opera....

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aduew9uo/)

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky();
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
        <td class="ui sticky">asdasd</td>
        <td class="ui sticky">asddd</td>
        <td class="ui sticky">asdda</td>
        <td class="ui sticky">asdddd</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Which version of each browser ? From your fiddle I get the same output (the cells on top of each other) for Chrome 44 and FF 38 (and IE11).

Comment: Chrome: 43.0.2357.134 Firefox: 39.0

Comment: Just click on table date to see the result. On chrome all is fine, on Firefox all on top of another

Comment: Some quick notes: the fiddle currently gives the table a class of `cellled`; it should be `celled`. Also, the `<td>` tags in your header should be `<th scope="col">` if you're going for semantics (the other `<td>` tags are fine). But after I make these corrections, Chrome and Firefox both show very similar behavior, and it's closer to what Firefox was doing before than what Chrome was doing.

Comment: position:fixed IS like position:absolute That's how fixed is supposed to work.

Comment: Still no proper solution for that issue